# Is Certified | Ethical Hacker (C|EH) a scam or legitimate?

Tags: authentication, certificates, authorization

I've been doing a lot of research on Certified | Ethical Hacker (**C|EH**) to see if it's a credible certification. But I've stumbled across a Wikipedia article on it and discovered that the sources are straight from the company **EC-Council** the ones that made the certification in the first place. The writing of the article sounds like it's marketing it to you. It didn't have a wiki article on EC-Council itself and the founder and CEO is from India (I'm not being racist or anything) I even signed up for it on the EC-Council website and got a message from the employee who is from India. Does anyone know the real history of the company or is it a scam?

Comment: It is not a scam.  It is of debatable value.   Because the answers are going to be purely opinion based, this is off topic.

Comment: @Xander I understand it's off topic but I really need to know if it gives you the right skills of being an Ethical Hacker?

Comment: OSCP is generally better regarded.  I would take a look at that instead.

Comment: @Xander alright I'll have a look of that. But do you have any valuable information on the valuable benefits Certified Ethical Hacker certificate?

Comment: "Does it give me the right skills?" and "what are the valuable benefits of C|EH"? are all purely opinion questions. Is the C|EH a scam and the history of EC Council is very easy to look up/

Comment: If you're asking whether the certificates will actually give you actual knowledge, no they're all scams: CEH, OSCP, CISSP, Security+, all of them are scams, no exceptions, yes that includes your pet certifications. No amount of certificates can replace real knowledge, experiences, reputation, and having that slightly paranoid attitude needed to properly be successful in the field. If you're just looking to get your foot in the door for the poor HRs, then having an extra certs or two won't hurt, but the real professionals can smell your real values whether or not you have certs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people in the security industry [do not think highly of EC-Council](http://attrition.org/errata/charlatan/ec-council/), the company behind the Certified Ethical Hacker (C|EH) certification. That doesn't mean that the ceritification itself is a scam, though.

In my experience, there are very few security certs that actually provide value. Sure, studying the topics that are covered on the exam can absolutely be helpful, and may improve your knowledge, but having certifications -- with the possible exception of the [OSCP](https://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/oscp-offensive-security-certified-professional/) -- doesn't really show that you know much about security.

That said, it depends on why you're looking to get certified in the first place. If your primary goal is demonstrating to non-technical hiring managers that you're somewhat qualified to do security work -- or if the jobs you're applying to require security certifications -- then it can absolutely be valuable. If, however, you're trying to show a technical audience that you know your stuff, holding a CEH will not accomplish your goal.

As someone who hires security engineers at several different levels, I think of CEH on about the same level as Security+ -- that is to say, it's better than nothing, but not particularly impressive. It certainly won't get you a job, but frankly, neither will more well-known certs like the CISSP.

I hope this helps. If you find the material for CEH interesting, I'd say go ahead and take the exam. It might help get your resume in the door (HR screeners will probably like it), and if you think it looks silly, you're not required to keep it on your resume.

Good luck!

Comment: "It won't get you a job" -- but it might get you past the keyword-filter that recruiters use to make sure candidates "meet the requirements".